# Joining 2 tables in pyspark, multiple conditions, left join?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have 2 tables like below. My code below is joining 2 tables (left join). The problem is I have to do the same join twice. The first join is happening on log_no and LogNumber which returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The second join is doing the same thing but on the substring of log_no with LogNumber. for example, 777 will match with 777 from table 2, 777-A there is no match but when using a substring function 777-A becomes 777 which will be matched in table 2.

[image]

Instead of creating 2 separate joins like below, how can I cover both scenarios with one join instead. Code below:

```
# first join to match 1234-A (table 1) with 1234-A (table 2)
df5 = df5.join(df_app, trim(df5.LOG_NO) == trim(df_app.LogNumber), "left")\
         .select (df5["*"], df_app["ApplicationId"])
df5 = df5.withColumnRenamed("ApplicationId","ApplicationId_1")
        
# second join with substring function, to match 777-C with 777, 
# my string is longer than my examples, this is why I have a substring for the first 8 characters. I provided simple examples.

df5 = df5.join(df_app, substring(trim(df5.LOG_NO), 1, 8) == trim(df_app.LogNumber), "left")\
         .select (df5["*"], df_app["ApplicationId"])
df5 = df5.withColumnRenamed("ApplicationId","ApplicationId_2")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two join conditions using a bitwise OR:

```
df5 = df5.join(df_app, 
               (trim(df5.LOG_NO) == trim(df_app.LogNumber)) |
               (substring(trim(df5.LOG_NO), 1, 8) == trim(df_app.LogNumber)), 
               "left") \
         .select(df5["*"], df_app["ApplicationId"])
```

Comment: I'm confused why AND? that means both conditions must be true. If the first condition fails, then substring condition should be true.

Comment: @AJR Sorry, should be OR. Edited my answer.

Comment: My program is not finishing .... I had to kill it after double the time. Usually my glue job takes about 22 minutes to finish, I let it run for 44 minutes and it was still running ... I think for some reason the bitwise OR put my program in a loop and its not finishing. Any other advise?? thanks

Comment: @AJR Try it with a smaller dataframe first to check that it does the job correctly. There is no way that the 'OR' will put your program in a loop. It's simply impossible.